# Gitlab - unable to clone via SSH, but SSH works itself

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

What I'm trying to achieve is to clone into a repo from my local gitlab instance using SSH, what I have done is:

1. I have created a user with an SSH key in gitlab
2. In the project I have added user as a maintainer, he also has an Admin rights
3. I'm cloning using myusername@address:git/name.git which ends up with msg:

```
    fatal: 'git/name.git' does not appear to be a git repository
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

4. When I simply connect using SSH it seems to work perfectly fine

```
ssh username@address
username@address's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-118-generic x86_64)
```

I have tried to check gitlab's auth.log but it's empty, and btw I'm trying to clone from a windows machine. I'm not using standard git account here, I want users to have to use their own account to clone. Cloning via http works fine.
Can you guys please advise what am I doing wrong here or how should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Try to clone a github or gitlab repository, to validate another issues.

Comment: I just did, cloned using my key and some repo at git@github.com... and it worked fine there.

Comment: How is your gitlab installed? It looks to me that it's SSH agent is not listening on port 22

Comment: I'm able to connect via SSH perfectly fine to this machine, using the account Im trying to use with Git.

Comment: I don't doubt it - doesn't mean that gitlab is listening on the port you expect it to though. Also - if memory serves it usually requires the "git" user when logging in - not your own user.

Comment: if you have the web GUI running, copy the ssh uri you get from the "Clone" button on your project's page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item 3 here is almost certainly where you are going wrong:

> I'm cloning using myusername@address:git/name.git ...

The main reason for setting up a fancy system like GitLab is so that you *don't* log in as yourself.  Instead, you log in as `git@hostname`: in fact, *everyone* who uses the fancy setup, which lets multiple users collaborate on shared repositories, logs in this way.  The underlying OS then handles the repositories, whose permissions are given only to the `git` user (or other user of your choice: in this case, replace `git@` with `user@` everywhere).  The fancy system uses ssh's authentication to figure out who's coming in as `git@host`, looks in *its own* permissions tables to see who has which permissions on which repositories, and then grants or denies permission itself, without the OS getting involved at all.

Hence, none of the repositories on the server are in *anyone's* user workspace.  They are in the pseudo-user's home directory (`~git`), or somewhere else as dictated by the fancy software.  Logging in on the server as yourself, you won't be able to access the repositories, as they're owned by the pseudo-user, so the OS itself will deny permission to you (at least for writing: you might be able to *read* them, and of course on a Linux-like system, if you have superuser or sudo privileges you can use that to get to the repositories for special maintenance operations, for instance).

If everyone in your organization has direct ssh access, you can use the much simpler and less-fancy basic group-shared Linux modes for repositories.  Of course this also lacks all the superstructure for doing code reviews, providing protected branches, and so on.  You don't need GitLab or anything like it at all.  This makes it much more pleasant to use, but is less appropriate (or not at all appropriate) for typical corporate settings—which is why things like GitLab exist in the first place.

Note that when you go in through a web server, the *web server* sits between you and the OS.  So you have probably set up your web server as directed in your GitLab documentation, and the web server is using GitLab as the appropriate pseudo-user.  That would then explain why you cannot get to the repositories as yourself.  You must set up the pseudo-user (as described in your GitLab documentation) and then log in as `git` (or whatever pseudo-user you designate), using an SSH key-pair where the public key has been loaded into the pseudo-user's setup so that it will know that it's you coming knocking at the pseudo-user's login.